# How to create a Dictionary(TKey, TValue) property

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I try to create a property that holds a dictionary.

```
Private _dic As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
Public Property DicProp(ByVal val1 As Decimal, ByVal val2 As Decimal,
                          ByVal val3 As Decimal) As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
    Get
        Return _dic
    End Get
    Set(value As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal))
        value.Add("Value1", val1)
        value.Add("Value2", val2)
        value.Add("Value3", val3)
    End Set
End Property
```

I tried to fill the property with

```
        .DicProp(1,2,3)
```

But I get the message `"Property access must assign to the property or use its value"`. Could anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `Set` section of the property entirely:

```
Private _dic As New Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
Public Property DicProp As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
    Get
        Return _dic
    End Get
End Property
```

You will still be able to make changes to this property, even without a setter!

```
MyObject.DicProp.Add("Value1", 1.0D)
MyObject.DicProp.Add("Value2", 2.0D)
MyObject.DicProp.Add("Value3", 3.0D)
```

This works, because it's equivalent to this code:

```
Dim temp As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
temp = MyObject.DicProp ' Use the *Get* portion of the property in your object to retrieve the dictionary
temp.Add("Value1", 1.0D) ' Then use the Add (or Set properties) on the retrieved dictionary object
```

Comment: You may wish to edit your post.  The Property declaration seems to have three indexers!  (val1, val2, and val3).

Answer (score 1):

You want a function (or Sub in this case for VB) not a property as properties can only get or set a single value.

```
Public Sub AddValues(ByVal val1 As Decimal, ByVal val2 As Decimal, ByVal val3 As Decimal)
   _dic.Add("Value1", val1)
   _dic.Add("Value2", val2)
   _dic.Add("Value3", val3)
End Sub
```

And then:

```
AddValues(1,2,3)
```